# MongoDB -Update one field value from multiple sub directories

Tags: mongodb

Actually this is the first time I am using MongoDB

I have the fields list given below:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e589db3361b71129079f559"),
"branch_id" : "BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91",
"inventory" : [ 
    {
        "inventory_stock_id" : "MED111",
        "stock_name" : "Anacin",
        "stock_point" : "2",
        "batch" : [ 
            {
                "quantity" : 50,
                "manuf_date" : "10-01-2020",
                "exp_date" : "26-03-2020"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to subtract the fields of **quantity** and update fields expected result:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e589db3361b71129079f559"),
"branch_id" : "BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91",
"inventory" : [ 
    {
        "inventory_stock_id" : "MED111",
        "stock_name" : "Anacin",
        "stock_point" : "2",
        "batch" : [ 
            {
                "quantity" : 10,
                "manuf_date" : "10-01-2020",
                "exp_date" : "26-03-2020"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

My MongoDB Query is:

```
inventory_item_update = db.inventory.update(
                    {
                        "branch_id": "BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91",
                        "inventory.inventory_stock_id": "MED111"
                    },
                    {'$set': {"inventory.inventory_stock_id.batch.quantity":40}}, multi=True)
```

Here It will not subtracted the quantity but I try to update the field but it's not worked

I given **quantity** value 40,It must be **subtract** the quantity value from **$gte** and want to update it.

so anyone help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   { branch_id: "BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91" },
   { $inc: { "inventory.$[item].batch.$[b].quantity": -40 } },
   {
      arrayFilters: [
         { "item.inventory_stock_id": "MED111" },
         { "b.quantity": { $gte: 40 } }
      ]
   }
)
```

This will update **all** `batch` elements in case you have more than one.

Comment: What if the existing quantitiy is less than 40, and quantity cannot be negative? One case could be that the update is scrapped altogether, another case could be that the entire available quantity is depleted (in other words, set to 0). How can those cases be handled? Can they be handled in one mongodb query, or will we first need to read and implement those cases in our code?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit,I used this above query but I get this error "upsert must be True or False" how to set upsert in the above query

Comment: Check your command syntax, most likely you forgot just a comma or similar. The command in my answer is working.

Comment: I find the issue and above query works thanks @WernfriedDomscheit